# Javascript how to binarize image data from buffer

Tags: javascript, electron, buffer

I am creating an Electron app and I have buffered data from an image in the form:

```
[137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 2, 88, 0, 0, 0, 120, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 161, 55, 27, 148, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 11, 18, 0, 0, 11, 18, 1, 210, 221, 126, 252, 0, 0, 32, 0, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 218, 236, 189, 7, 152, 84, 69, 214, 255, 191, 207, 255, 217, 223, 238, 42, 97, 102, 58, 231, 112, 67, 231, 137, 12, 57, 231, 201, 211, 211, 211, 57, 119, 79, 102, 72, 2, …]
```

Which I need to convert to black and white but whenever I run it through the binarize function below, I get errors like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mime' of null`.

I'm using this code to convert to black and white:

```
function binarize(data) {
  var RED_INTENCITY_COEF = 0.2126;
  var GREEN_INTENCITY_COEF = 0.7152;
  var BLUE_INTENCITY_COEF = 0.0722;

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    var brightness = RED_INTENCITY_COEF * data[i] + GREEN_INTENCITY_COEF * data[i + 1] + BLUE_INTENCITY_COEF * data[i + 2];
    // red
    data[i] = brightness;
    // green
    data[i + 1] = brightness;
    // blue
    data[i + 2] = brightness;
  }
  return data;
}

data = binarize(data)
```

The image is in buffer only and does not need to be displayed anywhere. The image is fetched from a png file.

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure what you mean. That's the error message I get if the data is changed with the binarize function.

Comment: So we are missing the part where you have `data = someProcessCreatingSomeObject(yourArray)`

Comment: @mplungjan ...what do you mean....? Starting to feel like this is the opening to that episode of Boston Legal where Denny keeps asking 'what do you mean'.

Comment: Don't we have `data = binarize(data)` .....? Please clarify what you're referring to...

Comment: @mplungjan The data code I posted at the top is the image data array before binarisation. This array can be processed no problem without throwing any mime error message so must include whatever is needed. After going through the binarize function it throws the mime error.

Comment: _After going through the binarize function it throws the mime error_ when doing what with the binarized data? Assign it to an image?

Comment: @mplungjan After going through the binarize function nothing can be done with it, it can no longer be written to file as an image, I can no longer process it with Tesseract which is what I want to do. The untouched data array is fine, I can write it to an image file, process it or do whatever.. I really just want to know how to properly binarize this data array. Unless that is not possible.